# Go language - opening a pipe to a command exec after redirection output causes EOF

Tags: go

I am trying to redirect the output of a process to one place, and then to open a pipe to the process , read its data and send the data to a predefined web socket connection --> but i get EOF.

For example :

```
myCmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "some command")

myCmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

myCmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

appOut, _ := lsCmd.StdoutPipe()
```

And then i am calling this go routine:

```
data := make([]byte, 1000)

for {

    for {

        n, err := appOut.Read(data)

        if err == nil && n > 0 {
            myConnection.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, data[0:n])
        }

      if err != nil {
        log.Printf("App exited. err: %s, Error ", err)
       }

    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what i have done wrong  ?
I must mention that even if I change the order of the line (openning the pipe before the redirection it still happens)

Comment: You have an infinite loop that reads indefinitely from the reader, `io.Reader`s are defined as returning EOF when they reach the end of the content to be read. Is `appOut` an infinite stream? If not then you're seeing normal behaviour.